# The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters

Tags: botframework

I am trying to deploy a bot to azure. I am using Bot SDK V3 template. It works locally and tested it with emulator. When I try to publish the project to Azure, I am getting this error:

"obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.    Microsoft.Bot.Sample.SimpleEchoBot      0"

I enabled longpaths on the machine by setting the reg key at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled to 1. Still, same error.

I also created a short folder on C drive as C:\D and in folder D, I created the VS solution. Still, same error.

I am not able to publish the project to azure. What needs to be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue and am ***not yet*** sure of the root cause, other than it is nesting package objects within package objects.

As a quick fix/workaround; you can remove everything under obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp and then republish.

Optionally, you can use a Pre-build event in your project file to clear out older packages when you build:

```
set "packagetemp=\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp"
rmdir /Q /S $(ProjectDir)%packagetemp%
```